# Can we create executable jar files in javascript similar to java executable jar files?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jar

I generally convert simple daily repetitive tasks into a java program with user inputs and outputs. This is later converted to executable jars which i can run through bat file and verify output through command prompt.

Can i do the same with javascript ?

Below is one of the example of a string conversion file which helps me format the file path string into a windows applicable file path format.  Is it possible to write similar program in javascript and convert the file into a jar which i can later run similarly through bat file or any medium with user inputs?

```
package Strings;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class replace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your input string : ");
        String inputstring=  sc.nextLine();
        String outputstring=inputstring.replace("%20", " "); 
//replaces %20 to space
        System.out.println(outputstring.replace("/", "\\"));   
// replaces slashes to proper format for windows and provides out put in cmd prompt when run through bat
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need jvm to run jars anyway. You can just run `.js` file with a `.bat` if you have node.js installed

Comment: I would also really recommend you check out SED (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/) regular expressions can be a bit tricky, but once you start using this and getting the hang of it I think you'll find it can improve these common jobs that you reference.

Comment: What's the point, surely you could just run a batch file to prompt for a string and replace characters in it. Alternatively use a powershell script and perform full uri/html decoding.

Comment: This question here is not for string conversion optimisation and that was just an example of the repetitive task that i use bat files for.  The question is on the conversion method of js files to jar or bat format to run a specific function

Comment: This site is for specific programming code problems, not advice on software, programs, tools, or reference material, on how to program.

Comment: Caution: replacing “%20” with a space is *not* sufficient, by itself, for decoding a URI.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by **@Konrad**, you will definitely need jvm to run the jar. But if generating jars is not your top priority and you want to use cmd to achieve the same result using `node.js`. You can do something like below:

```js
// myProgram.js
const readline = require('readline');
const path = require('path');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Enter your input string: ', (inputstring) => {
  const outputstring = inputstring.replace('%20', ' ').replace('/', '\\');
  console.log(path.normalize(outputstring));
  rl.close();
});
```

In you cmd, you can then run

> node myprogram.js

As per the **OP's latest comment**, I can think of one way to achieve the result;

There is a npm package called **[`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)** which you can use to convert your Javascript files to executable file that can be run on windows.

You can run below commands:

1. `npm i -g pkg` - Globally install `pkg` npm module.
2. `pkg myprogram.js --targets win` - To generate executable file for windows. You can refer the docs for other OS.

This creates the executable file which you can double-click and run.